# Google password list recovery

Tags: chromebook, google-chrome-os

My complete Passwords listing has been lost.  My ChromeBook lost all power last nite. When recharged and rebooted all my info including Favorites and ALL my passwords were gone!  Checking I found the same on my sndroid phone!  How do I recover this info????

Comment: Have you already look at passwords.google.com?

Comment: Not sure why this was migrated to SU. The syncing of the passwords occurred over the Google accounts services.